# Execute custom Javascript function on button click in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

I am beginner in Angular 4 and writing a login component in Angular 4. On click of a Forgot password I want to flip the controls on page to show Reset password elements. I have a javascript function created called rotateCard(this) which I want to call on button click. It is inline javascript in html. I have added html in component.html. below is the code.

but it is giving error as "ReferenceError: rotateCard is not defined"

```
<form (ngSubmit)="doLoginUser()" #login="ngForm" >

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="main">
                                <img src="../../../../images/logo.png" class="crm-logo" width="139" height="43" />
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control crm-field" placeholder="Email"
                                        id="inputEmail" name="username" ngControl="username" required
                                        autofocus [(ngModel)]="username">                                        
                                    </div>                                   
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control crm-field" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                                        id="inputPassword" ngControl="password" required [(ngModel)]="password">
                                    </div>                                   
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block orange-btn">LOGIN</button>
                                </form>
                                <button class="btn btn-simple login-link" onClick="rotateCard(this)">
                                    Forgot Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end login -->
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="main">
                                <img src="../../../../images/logo.png" class="crm-logo" width="139" height="43" />
                                <p class="title">Forgot Password</p>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control crm-field" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block orange-btn">RESET PASSWORD</button>
                                </form>
                                <button class="btn btn-simple login-link" onClick="rotateCard(this)">
                                    Login
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end forgot password -->
                </div> <!-- end card -->
            </div> <!-- end card-container -->
        </div> <!-- end col md 5 -->
    </div> <!-- end row -->
    <div class="space-200"></div>
    </div>

</form>

<script src="../../../../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../../js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function rotateCard(btn){
        var $card = $(btn).closest('.card-container');
        console.log($card);
        if($card.hasClass('hover')){
            $card.removeClass('hover');
        } else {
            $card.addClass('hover');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Important for your next question: only post code related to the question, not everything. Nobody want's to read through all of that.

Comment: Try `(click)="rotateCard($event)"` instead of `onClick="rotateCard($event)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this in 3 steps.

1. I changed binding to (click)="rotateCard(this).
2. Added type="button" property to button.
3. Installed jquery through npm install and added those in to angular-cli.json

This helped loading the jquery and now the inner method written in component.ts is getting called.

Thank you everyone for responding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute functions if someone clicks on a element, you could add the `(click)` listener to your element.

Like this:

```
<button (click)="yourFunction()">Send</button>
```

Then add the function in your component:

```
yourFunction() {
    //your logic 
}
```

I hope that helps you out.

Like to official documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 0):

Why don' t put it in the component.ts file? .. and also remember in Angular 4 you can set `css animation directly from Component.ts` (`https://angular.io/guide/animations`) ..

So for example in your component.html .. something like:

```
<button class="btn btn-simple login-link" (click)="rotateCard()">
                                    Login
                                </button>
```

then in you Component.ts file:

in the `header section (near import )` ..

```
declare var $:any;
```

then after in your ComponentClass

```
rotateCard(){
        var $card = $("#USE ID NOT THIS FOR SELECTOR").closest('.card-container');
        console.log($card);
        if($card.hasClass('hover')){
            $card.removeClass('hover');
        } else {
            $card.addClass('hover');
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried to do implement this way, now there is not error,, but the function rotateCard() is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

> It is inline javascript in html

You shouldn't really do this. Looking at your function it looks pretty trivial to move this into the component definition rather than have it in the HTML.

Without seeing the component though I can't be much more help